# Golang test complain about sub package version

Tags: go, testing, package

HI I have my app that has a structure like this:

```
root/
 main.go
 pkg_a/
  fileUtil.go
 pkg_b/
  writeData.go
  writeData_test.go
```

either writeData* file import the package "pkg_a". When I was developing in master branch either "go build" and "go test" work well. When I switched to another branch, go build still continue to work but go test complained about "pkg_a" with:

> no matching versions for query "latest"

But, if i remove the import of the package from writeData_test.go (still used into writeData.go) go test work well. Obviously writeData_test.go call function contained in writeData.go that uses function within fileUtil.go.

What can be the problem? thank in advanced for the help

Comment: What's the difference between the `go.mod` files in each branch?

Comment: Also, how do you call the `go test` command?

Comment: I call test directly within the package, but now I have reopen the project and it's work... perhaps a visual studio code bug or cache issues??? very strang.. thank for the reply

Answer (score 0):

*** resolved ***
Reopen the project and let visual studio code import itself the package finding the function, fix the issues!